# Need help to extract comments from c file

Tags: c, unix

i just need help of how to extract comments from input text file and paste them in output file using C language in Unix command line. I don't need the code. Just give me favor of guiding me please. Here is what I want.

**Input:**

```
If the input file input_0.txt contains 
/* This is a single-line C comment */ 
#include <stdio.h>
/******  
* This is a nicely formatted  
* multi-line comment.  
******/ 
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{   
  // This is a C++ comment. 
}
```

**Output:**

```
Then the execution of the program would be as follows. 
$ ./Comments < input_0.txt 
This is a single-line C comment 
This is a nicely formatted 
multi-line comment. 
This is a C++ comment.
```

Here is my code which i modified from the Respected @David C. Rankin's code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXC 1024

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

/* Variables for removing comments*/
int ch, i = 0, flag = 0, prev = '\0';
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    char fname[MAX], temp[] = "temp.txt";
/* Variables for removing comments*/    

int inmulti = 0,
    insingle = 0,
    longline = 0;
char buf[MAXC] = "";

 FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;


/* validate file open for reading */

if (!fp) {  
    fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
}

/* open the temporary file in write mode */
    fp2 = fopen(temp, "w");

    /* error handling */
    if (!fp2) {
            printf("Unable to open temporary file!!\n");
            return 0;
    }


while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {     /* read upto MAXC into buf */
    char *p = buf;                  /* pointer to buf */
    size_t len = strlen (buf);      /* get length */

    if (longline) {                 /* is this 2nd read of long line? */
        if (insingle) {             /* are we in a single comment? */
            printf ("%s", buf);     /* print it, get next buf */
            continue;
        }
        else                        /* otherwise, reset insingle flag */
            insingle = 0;
    }

    if (inmulti) {                  /* are we in a multi-line comment? */
                        /* (note: you need to check if quoted here) */
        if (strstr (buf, "*/")) {   /* does buf contain ending? */
            inmulti = 0;            /* reset inmulti comment */
        }
        printf ("%s", buf);         /* print the line */
        continue;       /* (note: end can be before end of line) */
    }

    if (len && buf[len-1] != '\n')  /* check if end of line read */
        longline = 1;               /* if not, set longline */
    else
        longline = 0;               /* or, reset it */

    while (*p && *p != '/') p++;    /* find start (or end) of comment */
    if (!*p) continue;              /* none found, get next buf */

    if (*(p + 1) == '/') {          /* start of single line comment */
                        /* note: must make sure not part of path here */
        insingle = 1;               /* set single-line comment flag */
        printf ("%s", buf);         /* print line */
    }                   /* note: can print from p for comment only */
    else if (*(p + 1) == '*') {     /* start of multiline comment */
        if (!strstr (p + 2, "*/")) {    /* check for ending */
            inmulti = 1;            /* set multiline flag */
        }
        printf ("%s", buf);         /* print the line */
    }                   /* note: can print from p for comment only */
    else if (p > buf && *(p - 1) == '*') {  /* was / end of multi? */
        printf ("%s", buf);         /* end of multi line comment */
        inmulti = 0;
    }
}
rewind(fp);
 /* removes comments from the given input file */
    prev = fgetc(fp);
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {

            /* flag is 1 - double slash comment */
            if (flag == 1) {
                    /* skip the contents until you detect \n */
                    if (ch == '\n') {
                            flag = 0;
                            prev = fgetc(fp);
                    }
                    continue;
            }

            /* flag is 2 - slash arsterix comment */
            if (flag == 2) {
                    /* skip the contents until you detect asterix slash */
                    if (ch == '/' && prev == '*') {
                            flag = 0;
                            prev = fgetc(fp);
                    }
                    continue;
            }

            /* checking for double slash comment */
            if (ch == '/' && prev == '/') {
                    flag = 1;
            } else if (prev == '/' && ch == '*') {
                    /* slash asterix comment */
                    flag = 2;
            } else {
                    /* contents outside of comments */
                    fputc(prev, fp2);
            }
            prev = ch;
    }


if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

/* closing the input file */
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need a parser.  Look at clang.

Comment: @SLaks can you please guide me more.

Comment: Or simply read each line with `fgets` and determine if the first non-whitespace characters are `//` or the opening for a multi-line `/*` (and if so, you know all lines until the close are included).

Comment: There are many other questions about this on SO. Note that `printf(“/* This is not a comment +/\n”);`

Comment: @DavidBowling i have to do this in ubuntu that's why i add unix command line.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Can you please make an algorithm if possible?

Comment: We aren’t here to do this for you

Comment: Sure, I'm happy to provide an example. This is basic nuts-and-bolts parsing that provides are good learning opportunity. Give me a few minutes and I'll rough something out.

Comment: @Joe I don't say provide me code, just an algorithm by which i can code myself.

Comment: The algorithm IS the answer.  @DavidC.Rankin gave some pointers above; what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, to do this correctly, there are many more conditions that need to be checked for (such as `"//"`, `"/*"` or `"*/"` appearing as part of a path, or within a string). Making use of regular expressions is also another way to approach this.

If I understand you correctly, and you a looking to parse comment lines of a source file using basic C, then the following is a quick example of reading all lines in a file (which is provided as the 1st argument, or on `stdin`) and looking for single-line or multi-line comment delimiters.

This is not intended to be complete and cover all corner-cases or cases where the delimiters appear within literals, defines, etc.., but some care has been taken to note where additional code should be added to address those concerns.

The basic approach is to read a line in `MAXC` (`1024` byte chunks) and keeping track of 3 flags. `longline` meaning the line exceeds `MAXC` chars and you have read the 2nd (or 3rd, or 4th...) buffer full. `inmulti` tracking whether you are in a multi-line comment. Finally `insingle` where you are within a single-line comment that may exceed `MAXC` chars. The read loops checks and acts based upon the state of the flags, while looking for the end of a multi-line comment (if within one). The code also checks for multi-line comment start and end -- all within one line.

Given those qualifications, you could start with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXC 1024

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int inmulti = 0,
        insingle = 0,
        longline = 0;
    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {     /* read upto MAXC into buf */
        char *p = buf;                  /* pointer to buf */
        size_t len = strlen (buf);      /* get length */

        if (longline) {                 /* is this 2nd read of long line? */
            if (insingle) {             /* are we in a single comment? */
                printf ("%s", buf);     /* print it, get next buf */
                continue;
            }
            else                        /* otherwise, reset insingle flag */
                insingle = 0;
        }

        if (inmulti) {                  /* are we in a multi-line comment? */
                            /* (note: you need to check if quoted here) */
            if (strstr (buf, "*/")) {   /* does buf contain ending? */
                inmulti = 0;            /* reset inmulti comment */
            }
            printf ("%s", buf);         /* print the line */
            continue;       /* (note: end can be before end of line) */
        }

        if (len && buf[len-1] != '\n')  /* check if end of line read */
            longline = 1;               /* if not, set longline */
        else
            longline = 0;               /* or, reset it */

        while (*p && *p != '/') p++;    /* find start (or end) of comment */
        if (!*p) continue;              /* none found, get next buf */

        if (*(p + 1) == '/') {          /* start of single line comment */
                            /* note: must make sure not part of path here */
            insingle = 1;               /* set single-line comment flag */
            printf ("%s", buf);         /* print line */
        }                   /* note: can print from p for comment only */
        else if (*(p + 1) == '*') {     /* start of multiline comment */
            if (!strstr (p + 2, "*/")) {    /* check for ending */
                inmulti = 1;            /* set multiline flag */
            }
            printf ("%s", buf);         /* print the line */
        }                   /* note: can print from p for comment only */
        else if (p > buf && *(p - 1) == '*') {  /* was / end of multi? */
            printf ("%s", buf);         /* end of multi line comment */
            inmulti = 0;
        }
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/comments.txt
/* This is a single-line C comment */
#include <stdio.h>
/******
* This is a nicely formatted
* multi-line comment.
******/
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
// This is a C++ comment.
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/comments <dat/comments.txt
/* This is a single-line C comment */
/******
* This is a nicely formatted
* multi-line comment.
******/
  // This is a C++ comment.
```

**note:** the worth in an exercise such as this is in the learning value stepping though a long string identifying certain individual characters, as well as in handling various flags and program states as you loop though a file.

---

**Reading Character-by-Character**

To switch from a *line-oriented* approach to a *character-oriented* approach (and adding a couple of states noted in the comments from chux), you will read the first character (save it), and then read the remaining characters in the file. This provides a way of comparing the *previous* to *current* to determine if you are within or without a *single-line* comment, a *multi-line* comment or *single* or *double* quotes.

Again, this isn't intended to catch every corner case, but the output was updated to not print the opening or closing comment delimiters. (you will need to tweak the printing of `*` within multi-line comments and quotes within comments to your taste).

Changing from reading with `fgets` to `fgetc`, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int inmulti = 0,    /* in multi-line comment flag */
        insingle = 0,   /* in single-line comment flag */
        insquo = 0,     /* within single-quotes */
        indquo = 0,     /* within double-quotes */
        c, prev = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if ((prev = fgetc(fp)) == EOF)      /* read 1st char */
        return 1;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {    /* read remaining */
        switch (c) {                    /* switch on c */
            case '/':
                if (prev == '/' && !(insquo | indquo))
                    insingle = 1;
                if (prev == '*' && !(insquo | indquo))
                    inmulti = 0;
                break;
            case '*':
                if (prev == '/' && !(insquo | indquo))
                    inmulti = 1;
                break;
            case '\n':
                insingle = 0;
                if (insingle || inmulti)
                    putchar (c);
                break;
            case '\'':
                insquo = insquo ? 0 : 1;
                break;
            case '"':
                indquo = indquo ? 0 : 1;
                break;
            default:
                if ((insingle || inmulti) && !(insquo | indquo))
                    putchar (c);
                break;
        }
        prev = c;
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    putchar ('\n');     /* tidy up with newline */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/commentsfgetc <dat/comments.txt
 This is a single-line C comment
 This is a nicely formatted
 multi-line comment.
 This is a C++ comment.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions over how characters are being identified or the code controlled to locate the start and end of the comment blocks.

Comment: Thanks alot. It will help me enough. Does i have to make a MAKEFILE  for it?

Comment: Just use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -o comments comments.c` to compile to the executable `comments` from the source file `comments.c`. (**note:** always compile with `-Wall -Wextra`, add `-pedantic` for even more warnings, and do not accept code until it compiles without warning.

Comment: Alright. Although i have to extract the text from comments also. You had printed out the comments as given in input file.

Comment: Well, that's just a few more additions. After using the pointer `p` to locate `'/`, you check the next char (is it `'/'` or `'*'`)., if so, move the pointer 2-chars forward and print the comment, e.g. `p += 2; printf ("%s", p);` which would print beginning immediately after the comment start. But recall, you can have `/******`. To skip all `'*'`, you would need `while (*p && *p == '*') p++;` then `printf ("%s", p);` There is no end of the tweaking you can do. Just think about what character `p` points to and either move forward or back until you get what you want.

Comment: Alright got it. I have made some changes so how can i show you? It's my first question here.

Comment: With more complex source, one may need to keep track of 5 states: In `/**/` comment, in `//` comment, in `""` string, in `''` constant, everything else.  Consider code `char *s = "/* */";` or `int x = '//';` or `z = "/*"; // comment */`.  Good luck.

Comment: Well, what you can do is **edit** your question and **add** the new code you have (or have questions) about at the end. **Note** -- do not erase your original question (or all the comments and answers will no longer make sense)

Comment: @chux I'm glad to have a count. I honestly started thinking through the corner cases, literals, quoted strings, etc., but never chased all the rabbit trails down to the point of putting a number to it. That would indeed add to the state gymnastics....

Comment: As it turns out, coded as a state machine, reading 1 `char` at a time, the code it no so big/complex.  GTG.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I updated my question, Kindly check it.

Comment: The biggest problem with your edit is `prev = fgetc(fp);` will begin reading at the end of the file as the code above reading line-by-line will have advanced the *file position indicator* to the end of file (where the next read come from in the file). To take a character-by-character approach, you will want to get rid of the `fgets (buf....` code and just do `int c; while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) { /* handle char-by-char testing */ }` It's a *pick one or the other* way of reading the file..

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  Can you please edit your code after fixing  my code?

Comment: Well, I would have to completely write another set of logic to handle the character-by-character processing of input instead of using the *line-oriented* approach above. It will take a bit, but I'll look at a rewrite. Meanwhile, in your edit to your question, just delete everything from `while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {` to the closing `}` (or just `rewind(fp);` after the closing `}`) and then your `prev = fgetc(fp);` will start reading characters. See if you can then locate the start and ends of both types of comments. The tests will be what I have except for the `strstr` call.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have placed the "rewind(fp);" just after the closing. Now what what you think the program is getting text out from the comments. For-example.  /**** I am a human ****/. Output=> I am a human. etc Where the program logic is breaking to produce output as it is?

Comment: See addition to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this shell script to do that, and save to a file `comments.txt`

```
cat generic.c | awk '/\/\// {print $0}; /\/\*/ {aux=1}; {if(aux) print $0}; /\*\// {aux=0}' > comments.txt
```

Good lucky

Answer (score 0):

I reworked the algorithm proposed by David. Used a buffer for one line

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int inmulti = 0,    /* in multi-line comment flag */
        insingle = 0;   /* in single-line comment flag */
    wint_t c, prev_1, prev_2;
    std::wstring str;

    FILE* fp = argc > 1 ? fopen(argv[1], "r,ccs=UTF-8") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf(stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if ((prev_1 = fgetwc(fp)) == WEOF)      /* read 1st char */
        return 1;
    if ((prev_2 = fgetwc(fp)) == WEOF)      /* read 2st char */
        return 1;

    while ((c = fgetwc(fp)) != WEOF) {    /* read remaining */
        if ((prev_1 == L'/' && prev_2 == L'*') && !insingle) {
            inmulti = 1;
            str += L"/*";
        }
        if ((prev_1 == L'*' && prev_2 == L'/') && inmulti) {
            inmulti = 0;
            str += L"\n";
        }
        if ((prev_1 == L'/' && prev_2 == L'/') && !inmulti) {
            insingle = 1;
            str += L"//";
        }
        if ((prev_1 == L'\r' || prev_2 == L'\n')) {
            insingle = 0;
            std::wcout << str.data();
            str.clear();
        }

        if (insingle || inmulti) {
            str += c;
        }

        prev_1 = prev_2;
        prev_2 = c;
    }

    std::wcout << str.data();

    if (fp != stdin) fclose(fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
/* This is a single-line C comment */ /* Next multiline 
   comment */
#include <stdio.h>
/******  
* This is a nicely formatted  
* multi-line comment.  
******/ 
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{   
  // This is a C++ comment.
}
```

**Example Use/Output:**

```
/* This is a single-line C comment */
/* Next multiline 
   comment */
/******  
* This is a nicely formatted  
* multi-line comment.  
******/
// This is a C++ comment.
```

*Compiled in VisualStudio, but the idea is easily portable to GNU C++.*